# How to perform a sum of an int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Given an array `A` of 10 `ints`, initialize a local variable called `sum` and use a loop to find the sum of all numbers in the array `A`.

This was my answer that I submitted:

```
sum = 0;
while( A, < 10) {
   sum = sum += A;
}
```

I didn't get any points on this question. What did I do wrong?

Comment: look up java for loops which is probably what your instructor wanted you to use.

Comment: How far along are you in the course?

Comment: What you did wrong was writing a program and then not running it to see if it compiled and did what you wanted.

Comment: @scrappedcola unfortunately, that is not the only and main mistake

Comment: int sum=Arrays.stream(A).sum();

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your syntax and logic are incorrect in a number of ways. You need to create an index variable and use it to access the array's elements, like so:

```
int i = 0;        // Create a separate integer to serve as your array indexer.
while(i < 10) {   // The indexer needs to be less than 10, not A itself.
   sum += A[i];   // either sum = sum + ... or sum += ..., but not both
   i++;           // You need to increment the index at the end of the loop.
}
```

The above example uses a `while` loop, since that's the approach you took. A more appropriate construct would be a `for` loop, as in Bogdan's answer.

Comment: @JordanWestlund: Welcome to StackOverflow. If I answered your question sufficiently, please mark the question as answered so other users know they don't need to pay attention to it anymore.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know I was suppose to do that. Were can i mark it as answered?

Comment: There is a grey tick below the score for this question. Click it and it will turn green.

Comment: Should not assume that you have actually been given an array of 10, should do a check for length i.e. A.length

Comment: @Clarkey: While this may not be as pretty or maintainable as you'd like, it does answer the question very directly. I could tell that the OP was struggling with the simplest of principles, so I opted not to confuse him by throwing in a `for` loop or a `.length` check (although I referred him to an answer that does). Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down, and consider whether this question really deserves your down-vote.

Comment: Or get rid of the i++ in the body by using a for loop.

Answer (score 50):

Once [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) is out (March 2014) you'll be able to use streams:

```
int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();
```

or even

```
int sum = IntStream.of(a).parallel().sum();
```

Comment: *So* excited for Java 8. I doubt you'll see any performance benefit from `parallel` in this case, though. In fact, I bet performance will be significantly slower that way.

Comment: You'll be surprised. Here is a benchmarks I took that shows that the parallel version is much faster: http://www.thecoderzone.com/arrays-and-streams

Answer (score 8):

```
int sum=0;
for(int i:A)
  sum+=i;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
  sum += A[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you declare a variable, you need to declare its type - in this case: `int`.  Also you've put a random comma in the `while` loop.  It probably worth looking up the syntax for Java and consider using a IDE that picks up on these kind of mistakes.  You probably want something like this:

```
int [] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6, 7, 8, 9 , 10 };
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    sum += numbers[i];
}
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way to solve this question using For loops in Java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int size = numbers.length;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the existing answers.